# Car with floor-integrated battery pack

Tags: battery, automotive-design

Are there any other electric cars with a floor-integrated battery pack other than the Tesla?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about car technology in general and not about DIY.

Comment: A major UK manufacturer produced a modified electric van with a battery 'installation' quite similar to that in the picture. Unfortunately the installation virtually blew up, whilst on charge overnight. Circa 1985, testing was discontinued.

Comment: Well, this is a first step towards a DYI.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer is 'yes'. Today almost all electric cars have their battery pack floor integrated.

[Every Electric Car You Can Buy in 2022](https://www.motortrend.com/features/every-electric-car-you-can-buy/?slide=1)

Comment: This is a link only answer and doesn't answer the question. Not only that, but the link itself doesn't answer the question, either.

Comment: There are kits one can buy today, @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2.

Comment: How is DIY a "floor-integrated battery pack", which was your original question? Neither link specifies this and as well, it is still a link only answer.

Comment: Can explain over voice.

Answer (score 2):

Only if Tesla leases them rights to use [their patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120160583) on this. Tesla's patent was published on June 28, 2012, so I'm doubting there are any other vehicles with this same technology, at least using Tesla's patent.

I did find a separate patent filing by Ferrari which covers the use of floor mounted batteries in their [LeFerrari](http://www.motortrend.com/roadtests/exotic/1303_ferrari_laferrari_first_look/). I'm not sure how it truly differs from the Tesla design, but would assume it is substantial enough to not get sued by them.

I'm not seeing much else with this type of technology, but there may be some forthcoming.

Comment: Tesla has made all of their patents open source so there is no issue in potentially violating their patents.

Comment: Exactly, the evenly distributed battery-weight makes it a better design than the others.

Comment: Tesla hasn't patented floor mounted batteries — that would be too broad and any competent lawyer would get the patent tossed out (auto manufacturers have good lawyers). All they hold a patent for is their "improved integration system" on top of the basic concept. The patent mostly only covers Tesla's specific technique of creating noise and thermal isolation between the cabin and the road.

Answer (score 1):

The Ford Focus EV has two high voltage battery packs, one is in the rear cargo area and the other is located underneath the vehicle. I don't know if that is considered floor integrated but it isn't too different from what Tesla is doing.